# Show that $\frac{|F(z)-F(a)|}{|F(z)-\bar{F(a)}|}\le\frac{|z-a|}{|z-\bar{a}|}$ if $z\in\Pi^{+}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider $\Pi^{+}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\}$ and let $a\in\Pi^{+}$. Suppose that $F:\Pi^{+} \rightarrow \Pi^{+}$ is holomorphic. Prove that for all $z\in\Pi^{+}$ we have:
$$\frac{|F(z)-F(a)|}{|F(z)-\bar{F(a)}|}\le\frac{|z-a|}{|z-\bar{a}|}$$
Also, show that:
$$|F´(z)|\le\frac{Im(F(a))}{Im(a)}$$

Comment: Big hint:  Do you know Pick's Lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Pick's Lemma, we know that $\frac{|f(z_1) - f(z_2)|}{|1-\overline{f(z_1)}f(z_2)|} \leq \frac{z_1-z_2}{1-\overline{z_1}z_2}$ for any holomorphic function that maps the unit disk $D$ to itself.  Now, note that the map $H(z) =\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the upper half plane $\Pi^{+}$ to the unit disk.  Then, we see that $H \circ F \circ H^{-1}$ is a map from $D$ to $D$.  Now use Pick's Lemma above and simplify to get your result.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know the Schawarz-Pick theorem, with this is easy solve the problem